# How can I move UIBarButtonItem as image to the left side using it as menu button?

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, xcode9-beta

Whenever I try to set an image to a UIBarButtonItem, it gets put in the center of the bar. How can I move it to the left to use it as a menu button by setting the image of the button programmatically?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the left bar button image via your Navigation Controller in your storyboard instead.

Click on your Navigation Controller in Storyboard and ensure Navigation Bar is selected.

[image: Click on your Navigation Controller in Storyboard and ensure Navigation Bar is selected]

Choose your image for both Back and Back mask.

[image: Choose your back button image for both Back and Back mask]

Answer (score 0):

It can be fit to left of the NavigationBar button by "decreasing the resolution of image".